# New to jQuery with ASP.NET, simplifying jQuery code?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net, performance, simplify

So I have the below little number on a ASP.NET page.

The page consists of a gridview that I'm happy with, there is a checkbox in each row and once checked enables other controls in row, a save button iterates through the rows and actions into database.

My question is, the below code works how I want it, however is there any neat tricks to simplify further? More of a question to expand my knowledge? :)

```
`<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        //If checkbox in row is checked then
        $('[id^="MainContent_TCProcurement_TABPurchasing_GVQuotes_CBPurchased1_"]').click(function () {
            //Checkbox row id
            var idstr = this.id.replace('MainContent_TCProcurement_TABPurchasing_GVQuotes_CBPurchased1_', '');
            //Controls to alter
            var suppDDL = $("#MainContent_TCProcurement_TABPurchasing_GVQuotes_DDLSuppliers_" + idstr);
            var qtyPurchased = $("#MainContent_TCProcurement_TABPurchasing_GVQuotes_TBQuantity1_" + idstr);
            var ratePaid = $("#MainContent_TCProcurement_TABPurchasing_GVQuotes_TBRatePaid1_" + idstr);
            var buyer = $("#MainContent_TCProcurement_TABPurchasing_GVQuotes_TBBuyer1_" + idstr);
            var purchasedDate = $("#MainContent_TCProcurement_TABPurchasing_GVQuotes_TBDatePurch1_" + idstr);
            //If checked then remove disabled and enter some details
            if (this.checked) {
                suppDDL.removeAttr('disabled').removeClass('aspNetDisabled').removeAttr("style");
                qtyPurchased.removeAttr('disabled').removeClass('aspNetDisabled').removeAttr("style");
                ratePaid.removeAttr('disabled').removeClass('aspNetDisabled').removeAttr("style");
                buyer.removeAttr('disabled').removeClass('aspNetDisabled').removeAttr("style").val("<%= Session("loggedInUserName")%>");
                purchasedDate.removeAttr('disabled').removeClass('aspNetDisabled').removeAttr("style").val("<%= Date.Now()%>");
            } else {
                var newTBStyle = "font-family: Arial; font-size: 1em; background-color: rgb(235, 235, 228);";
                suppDDL.attr('disabled', 'disabled').addClass('aspNetDisabled').attr('style', newTBStyle);
                qtyPurchased.attr('disabled', 'disabled').addClass('aspNetDisabled').attr('style', newTBStyle);
                ratePaid.attr('disabled', 'disabled').addClass('aspNetDisabled').attr('style', newTBStyle);
                buyer.attr('disabled', 'disabled').addClass('aspNetDisabled').attr('style', newTBStyle).val("");
                purchasedDate.attr('disabled', 'disabled').addClass('aspNetDisabled').attr('style', newTBStyle).val("");
            }
        });

    });
</script>
```

Many thanks,
Ollie

Comment: Ouch those asp.net id names hurt my eyes. Can't you use simple id's instead of the old-style autogenerated ones ? Maybe you can't, but check this out: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/03/30/cleaner-html-markup-with-asp-net-4-web-forms-client-ids-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx Not only will it be easier on the eyes, but probably a lot less error prone too.

Comment: Not necessarily simpler, but I would move your `<script>` to a JavaScript file. This stops it from being downloaded each time your HTML page is requested and also allows the user to cache it on their computer so even the JavaScript may not be downloaded every time. This also promotes re-use, because multiple web pages can reference the same JavaScript file, but multiple pages cannot reference your in page `<script>`, as it is currently implemented.

Comment: instead of `attr`, prefer `prop`. Instead of `.prop("style")` there's a `.css()` function in JQuery. JQuery offers powerfull selectors. You are using the `id^=` "id starting with" like with old "getElementByID". You can use a more specific (and more readable) selector like "all checkboxes in my table named ***".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is untested, but you could add a common class to the items you want to enable and disable like this

```
class="rowControl"
```

Then, adjust it like this:

```
var myControl = $("[id~="+idstr+"].rowControl"); 
...
if (this.checked) {
   myControl.removeAttr('disabled').removeClass('aspNetDisabled').removeAttr("style");
} else {
   myControl.attr('disabled', 'disabled').addClass('aspNetDisabled').attr('style', newTBStyle);
}
```

While it doesn't do everything you need, it would adjust ALL elements with that class. You can add back the parts that are missing (like setting specific values).

NOTE: `var myControl = $("[id~="+idstr+"].rowControl");` will select all elements with the `id` containing `idstr` and class `rowControl`.

Comment: Thanks Robert for that, had a look into but going to leave as is, just because I have a few tabs in a tab container and with lots of controls etc in! Thanks as well, Karl Anderson thats what I would do, but just testing in page :) TCHdvlp, ahh okay, will look into! Thanks for that @davids, didn't look at it that way round!!

Comment: Are you responding to Robert's comment, or my answer?

Comment: No just failing to use the site, see above!